# What language Android Display Server SurfaceFlinger written in?

Tags: android, x11, surfaceflinger, wayland

What language Android Display Server SurfaceFlinger written in? Java or C.

What are some major differences between SurfaceFlinger and X11 or Wayland in terms of drivers, what language are they written in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SurfaceFlinger is written in C++.  You can find the [source code in AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/kitkat-release/services/surfaceflinger/), and some information in the [docs](http://source.android.com/devices/graphics.html).